# Symfony from styling time widgets

Tags: css, twig, symfony, styling, formbuilder

I am currently trying to style a form that is generated by symfony form builder.

there is a bootstrap overlay on it but i want to move the time widgets so they align next to each other.

[image: form view]

[image: twig template rows]
[image: formbuilder]

Comment: it is possible to see your form type ?

Comment: Thanks I edit my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display each input of your form independently using

`form_row(form.yourinputname)`

`form_row` is the combination of the field's label, errors and widget.

You can see the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html) about this

**EDIT:**

So if you want to display some widgets in one line you can do this (**you have to use a loop to display each input of your form collection**) :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myClass{
       .inline{
         display: inline-block;
       }
    }
</style>

<div class='myClass'>
  {% for business in form.businesshours %}
      <div class="inline">{{ form_row(business.day) }}</div>
      <div class="inline">{{ form_row(business.openTime) }}</div>
      <div class="inline">{{ form_row(business.breakStart) }}</div>
      <div class="inline">{{ form_row(business.breakEnd) }}</div>
      <div class="inline">{{ form_row(business.closeTime) }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: This does not really solve the problem it is just an other way to render the form but the styling stays the same, the goal is to get the time widgets on one line :/

Comment: Using form_row allows you to display input separately so you can after this use css to align time widget on one line, see my edit please

Comment: this just will just print 'form_row(business.day)' not the widget

Comment: I forgot `{{ }}` sorry  => `{{ form_row(business.day) }}`, Answer updated

Comment: mixed up your code to get the widgets and @Alsatian 's bootstrap to move them next to each other :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field

In this section there is a part to override the display of a single row, if you were to try something similar and give the div a class of your own you would probably be able to use css to style it.

This seems to be the page to go to for form styling and customization though.

Hope it helps

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block _datetime_row %} 
<div class="your_class"> 
{{ form_label(form) }} 
{{ form_errors(form) }} 
{{ form_widget(form) }} 
</div> 
{% endblock %}

{{ form_row(form.name) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add HTML to move each form row. (Same answer as @DOZ, but with bootstrap classes).

Remove `{{ form_row(form.businessHours) }}` and :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        {{ form_row(form.businessHours.Begin) }}
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        {{ form_row(form.businessHours.BeginPauze) }}
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        {{ form_row(form.businessHours.EindPauze) }}
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        {{ form_row(form.businessHours.Einde) }}
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: This would work but i can not access those rows since it is a partial form see my update ^

Comment: Any error ? Otherwise you can create your own `business_hours` block like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)